# QML: How to display certain parts of Text in different colors

Tags: qt, text, qml, qt5.12

I have the following QML Text embedded inside a Rectangle

```
Rectangle {
    id: textContainer
    border.color: "black"

    Text {
        id: myTextView
        anchors.fill: textContainer
        anchors.margins: 10
        font.pointSize: 4
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap

        Connections {
            target: cpp_controller
            onUpdateCalledFromCppCode: {
                myTextView.text = message + myTextView.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`onUpdateCalledFromCppCode` gets called like twice or thrice in a second which updates myTextView::text field. This works well and good.

**Question:**
Now, I want to display certain words/lines in the text in certain colors, given whatever is possible within QML. Like lets say, in one word in the variable `message` coming in `onUpdateCalledFromCppCode` says "Error", then I want to display that word or that whole line in Red. Is that possible in `QML`? How can I do that?

**Environment:**
I am am using commercial version of *Qt 5.12.5*

Comment: use html.......

Comment: Sounds like not possible in QML? :-(

Comment: See the markup example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#details

Comment: Text supports plain text and also rich text as HTML

Comment: @eyllanesc I have seen the discussion you tagged, I understand that one could hard code the Text like this `text: "<font color=\"#0000FF\">Blue</font> <font color=\"#FF0000\">Red</font>"` . But, how do I change it on the fly while updating?

Comment: The simplest solution is to implement it where you build "message", that is, on the C++ side.